# Reading through a .m File and Python keeps reading a character in the .m File as a line?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to read the text within a .m file in Python and Python keeps reading a single character within the .m file as a line when I use file.readline(). I've also had issues with trying to remove certain parts of the line before adding it to a list.

I've tried adjusting where the readline is on for loops that I have set up since I have to read through multiple files in this program. No matter where I put it, the string always comes out separated by character. I'm new to Python so I'm trying my best to learn what to do.

```py
# Example of what I did
with open('MyFile.m') as f:
   for line in f:
       text = f.readline()
       if text.startswith('%'):
         continue
       else:
          my_string = text.strip("=")
          my_list.append(my_string)
```

This has only partially worked as it will still return parts of lines that I do not want and when trying to format the output by putting spaces between new lines it output like so: 
Expected: "The String"
What happened: "T h e  S t r i n g"

Comment: once you have `for line in f:` the variable called `line` holds the current line. You don't need to call `f.readline()`

Answer (score 2):

Without your input file I've had to make some guesses here

Input file:

```
%
The
%
String
%
```

Solution:

```py
my_list = []

with open('MyFile.m') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('%'):
            my_list.append(line.strip("=").strip())
print(' '.join(my_list))
```

The readLine() call was unnecessary as the for loop already gets you the line.  The empty if was negated to only catch the part that you cared about. Without your actual input file I can't help with the '=' part. If you have any clarifications I'd be glad to help further.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Xander, you shouldn't call readline since the `for line in f` does that for you.

```
my_list = []
with open('MyFile.m') as f:
   for line in f:
       line = line.strip()   # lose the \n if you want to
       if line.startswith('%'):
           continue
       else:
           my_string = line.strip("=")
           my_list.append(my_string)
```